# ¿Cuál es el error de indentación en esta función de Python?

Tags: python, string, funciones, programación-funcional

Estoy creando una pequeña función para contar las vocales en una cadena de texto pero Python me está rebotando el error `"Unexpected indent"`. Sé que la función no es la mejor pero estoy ciñéndome a los parámetros de un ejercicio que intento resolver, así que sólo me interesa saber en dónde está el error de indentación.

El código y la cadena de texto de prueba están a continuación.

```
st= "El perro come zanahoria"


def contar_vocales(st):
    vocales= "aeiou"
    count_a= 0
    count_e= 0
    count_i= 0
    count_o= 0
    count_u= 0
    st=st.lower()
    for i in st:
        if vocales[0] in i:
            count_a+=1
    print("Hay",count_a,"letras a en el texto")        
        if vocales[1] in i:
            count_e+=1
    print("Hay",count_e,"letras e en el texto")
        if vocales[2] in i:
            count_i+=1
    print("Hay",count_i,"letras i en el texto")
        if vocales[3] in i:
            count_o+=1
    print("Hay",count_o,"letras o en el texto")
        if vocales[4] in i:
            count_u+=1
    print("Hay",count_u,"letras u en el texto")


contar_vocales(st)
```

El error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-588621c517e2>", line 16
    if vocales[1] in i:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Moví la indentación del segundo al quinto if pero me regresa cero para las vocales de la "e" a la "u". De antemano gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Los `print` "rompen" la indentación , imagino que deberían estar "dentro" de cada `if`.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho: Lo intenté como dices y no registra el conteo para las vocales de la "e" a la "u". No entiendo porqué no funciona; pensé que la indentación original era correcta. Saludos y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver el código.

Comment: Con que IDE estás trabajando  a veces el IDE tiene configurado la tabulacion como espacio y otras como barras espaciadora es muy común cuando programas en un lado y luego cambiarte no veas eso

Comment: @JackNavaRow Trabajo con Spyder, ahí la indentación es automática. Como he tenido errores similares en el pasado, traté de ser muy cuidadoso en la indentación. (Lo bueno es que Trewqa me hizo notar que era un problema de lógica y no tanto de indentación)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada vez que suma uno, a las variables que cuentan las vocales, muestra por pantalla los mensajes.

Si no me equivoco lo que busca es que al terminar de contar las vocales aparezcan esos mensajes, entonces ejecutaremos los print al acabar el for, de la siguiente manera:

```
st= "El perro come zanahoria"


def contar_vocales(st):
    vocales= "aeiou"
    count_a= 0
    count_e= 0
    count_i= 0
    count_o= 0
    count_u= 0
    st=st.lower()
    for i in st:
        if vocales[0] in i:
            count_a+=1     
        if vocales[1] in i:
            count_e+=1
        if vocales[2] in i:
            count_i+=1
        if vocales[3] in i:
            count_o+=1
        if vocales[4] in i:
            count_u+=1


    print("Hay",count_a,"letras a en el texto")  
    print("Hay",count_e,"letras e en el texto") 
    print("Hay",count_i,"letras i en el texto")
    print("Hay",count_o,"letras o en el texto")
    print("Hay",count_u,"letras u en el texto")


contar_vocales(st)
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta, aunque yo también lo hice igual me daba error en el segundo if, aún sigo sin entender, pero como dije, esta es la respuesta correcta

Comment: Gracias @Trewqa, funcionó de maravilla. Entiendo entonces que, más allá de ser un problema de indentación, la solución estriba en sacar los print del for para que cada contador se actualice correctamente. En verdad, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya Trewka te dio la solución, pero al parecer aún no has entendido tu error. El problema es que al ejecutar la función `print()` fuera de la identación del for, pues el intérprete asume   que ya has terminado el código que se ejecutará dentro de este ciclo, por tanto cualquier código que declares después de este `print()` ya no se ejecutará dentro de tu `for`.
Cometes el error de declarar luego la condicional `if` identada como si fuese parte del loop, cuando ya este ciclo cerró. Por eso te da el error de identación; fíjate bien en los cambios que plantea la solución de Trewka.
Debes empaparte más en la identación de Python, porque en su sintaxis la identación lo es todo.

Answer (score 0):

los print rompen la indentación porque no siguen el flujo, voy a poner '|' para que tengas una guia visual de lo que sucede:

```
st= "El perro come zanahoria"


def contar_vocales(st):
|    vocales= "aeiou"
|    count_a= 0
|    count_e= 0
|    count_i= 0
|    count_o= 0
|    count_u= 0
|    st=st.lower()
|    for i in st:
|    |    if vocales[0] in i:
|    |    |    count_a+=1
|    print("Hay",count_a,"letras a en el texto") 
|    |    if vocales[1] in i:
|    |    |    count_e+=1
|    print("Hay",count_e,"letras e en el texto")
|    |    if vocales[2] in i:
|    |    |    count_i+=1
|    print("Hay",count_i,"letras i en el texto")
|    |    if vocales[3] in i:
|    |    |    count_o+=1
|    print("Hay",count_o,"letras o en el texto")
|    |    if vocales[4] in i:
|    |    |    count_u+=1
|    print("Hay",count_u,"letras u en el texto")


|    contar_vocales(st)
```

como puedes ver los print no están dentro de los if

¿que entiende python?

```
st= "El perro come zanahoria"


def contar_vocales(st):  # definimos una función por tanto python espera un nivel mas de indentación
|    vocales= "aeiou"
|    count_a= 0
|    count_e= 0
|    count_i= 0
|    count_o= 0
|    count_u= 0
|    st=st.lower()
|    for i in st: # iniciamos un bucle for, otro nivel de indentación
|    |    if vocales[0] in i: # otro nivel por el if
|    |    |    count_a+=1
|    # Aquí python entiende que termina el for pues el nivel de indentación es el mismo
|    print("Hay",count_a,"letras a en el texto") 
|    |    # python no espera aquí ninguna indentación pues no hay ninguna función que lo requiera, deberia estar al nivel de print
|    |    if vocales[1] in i: # da error porque ya no estamos en el bucle for sino dentro de "def contar_vocales(st):"
|    |    |    count_e+=1
```